# Plugin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using gradle version 7.0 and plugin version 7.0.4 (using java language)
I had an error with title *projectname* failed. And no other information involved.
I changed gradle to version 7 and now I have an error :
`Plugin[id: 'com.android.application' version 7.0.4 apply:false] was not found in any of the following sources`

I changed gradle version but It still has the same error

Comment: Question needs clarification. you said you changed gradle to version 7 but wasn't it 7.0 in the the first place?

Comment: on my android studio it shows the last on is 7.4.2 you may written a wrong version that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Check the compatibility of your Gradle version with the Gradle plugin and your Android Studio version in the tables on following page:

[Android Gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)